# Issue with setting ACL in Debian. Why am I getting this error?

Tags: linux, debian

I am trying to set a folder to automatically make all folders within it writable and executable by nogroup.  What is the error in my below command?

```
root@debian:/opt/nzbget/downloads# sudo setfacl -R -d -m  nobody:nogroup:rx completed
setfacl: Option -m Invalid argument near character 8
```

I also tried

```
root@debian:/opt/nzbget/downloads# sudo setfacl -Rdm  nobody:nogroup:rx completed
setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 6
```

Where I read up on ACL
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-control-listsacl-linux/

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
setfacl -R -d -m u:nobody:rwX completed
setfacl -R -d -m g:nogroup:rwX completed
```

Also since you are root, no need for sudo.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!